# Detect if an element is selected in listbox or not through jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a multiselect listbox and before submitting the form i want to check whether user select any option or not through jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `.val()` function to get the selected values. For a multi select it returns an array of the selected values or null if no element has been selected:

```
if ($('#idofselect').val() != null) {
    // user has selected at least one value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you:

```
$("#formID").submit(function()
{
  var selectValue = $('#selectList').val();
  if(selectValue != null)
  {
      // blah
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#list option:selected').length
```

Will get the amount of selected objects i think. (replace '#list' with your selector obviously).